# Can we restrict the dimension of the domain to make the image lower dimensional?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be smooth. Does there always exist a hyperplane $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, such that $f(V)$ is contained in some hyperplane in the target?

Does the answer change if we only ask for $f(V)$ to be contained in some 
$n-1$ dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $$f_1(x,y)=(x\cos r^2+y\sin r^2, y\cos r^2-x\sin r^2)\qquad\text{with }r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
i.e., we rotate the more we move away from the origin. All lines (not only through the origin) get twisted, so are not ocontained in hyperplanes.

Next consider $$f_2(x,y)=f_1(x,y)\cdot \cos(r^2\sqrt 2).$$
Then the twirled lines even come back to the origin infinitely often and from irrationally spaced directions, i.e., from a dense set of directions, not fitting into a submanifold.

Comment: Thanks! This is a nice example. Can you please elaborate on what do you mean by "irrationally spaced directions"? How do you deduce that the images of the lines are not (embedded) submanifolds? Is it because we have self intersections? If I understood correctly, you meant to say that there is no "tangent line" at the origin, as we come back to it from different angles (directions). How can we convince ourselves that indeed dense different angles are realized?

Comment: BTW, I think that *more than two* angles already excludes the image being a one-dimensional embedded submanifold, as there won't be a tangent line. (two angles are possible when we approach a point from opposite directions, e.g. $0$ and $\pi$ like in a circle...)